# The Doctrine repository "Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository" must implement UserProviderInterface in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am getting above error when login. With property option in security.yml it is working. I have added the `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="versionR\userBundle\Entity\UserRepository")` line on my entity class, dobule checked path, cleared cache but no luck.

User entity class

```
<?php

namespace versionR\userBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
//use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="versionR\userBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="versionR\userBundle\Entity\Role", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->role = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $address
     */
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $username
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role->add($role);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /**
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->role->toArray();
    }

    /**
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    }
}
```

User repository class

```
<?php

namespace versionR\userBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
/**
 * UserRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @return \versionR\userBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        return $this->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $class = get_class($user);
        if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(
                sprintf(
                    'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                    $class
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->find($user->getId());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $this->getEntityName() === $class
        || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
    }
}
```

Both classes are in Entity directory. Any suggestions to solve this problem. I am using symfony 2.5.2

Comment: Verify you don't have any Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml or xml files lying around.

Comment: I haven't put `repository-class="versionR\userBundle\Entity\UserRepository"` after regenerating metadata files from db in User.orm.xml entity tag. Thanks for nice answer.